# My VM logs out of the desktop and goes into a blackscreen after some time

Tags: virtualbox

Using Gentoo linux on a VM, it works fine but if I leave the VM on the background after some time it logs off the desktop and then after it goes into a blackscreen and becomes unresponsive, why does this happen and what do I do to stop this?

Comment: perhaps it's going to sleep or hibernation - fix: disable sleep and hibernation